# android cached local files vs raw resources

Tags: android, caching, android-resources

Which is quicker/preferred. To save json data in the raw folder in resources, or in a local file in the apps cache using getCacheDir().

I'm thinking the cache route might have some speed improvements seeing as it is cached, or am I totally misunderstanding the concepts? (Highly possible)

Thanks in advance

Russ

Comment: cache directory is not really cached in the sense that it is in the device's RAM, but only in the device flash memory

Comment: So, as the raw folder is also in device flash memory, there is no difference?

Comment: raw folder might also be on SD card if you move the app to SD card

Answer (score 0):

I think RAW or ASSETS folder Maybe faster because it tightly integrated to the code and stored to device internal memory.

Comment: Do you mean compiled into the RAM/app? So raw files don't stay in their raw format on the internal storage of the device?

Comment: But then internal cache files are also stored in internal storage, so what's the difference?

Comment: When the device is low on internal storage space, Android may delete these cache files to recover space.

Comment: You've just made a very good point. I'll be getting this data from an api, which if the cache is deleted, I can just recall the api to get it. However, the api isn't ready yet so I will lose the file. 

Maybe cache in the future but raw for the time being. Thanks